# Debug Kit show duplicated query

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

i was doing the cake toutorial and once i've ended, was looking on Debugkit sql log, inside the edit page of the article and looks like that the query to retrieve the article data is dupicated for some reason.
This is the query shown twice:

```
SELECT 
  Articles.id AS `Articles__id`, 
  Articles.user_id AS `Articles__user_id`, 
  Articles.title AS `Articles__title`, 
  Articles.slug AS `Articles__slug`, 
  Articles.body AS `Articles__body`, 
  Articles.published AS `Articles__published`, 
  Articles.created AS `Articles__created`, 
  Articles.modified AS `Articles__modified` 
FROM 
  articles Articles 
WHERE 
  Articles.slug = 'first-post' 
LIMIT 
  1
```

This is the edit function:

```
   public function edit($slug)
    {
        $article = $this->Articles
            ->findBySlug($slug)
            ->contain('Tags') // load associated Tags
            ->firstOrFail();

        if ($this->request->is(['post', 'put'])) {
            $this->Articles->patchEntity($article, $this->request->getData(), [
                // Added: Disable modification of user_id.
                'accessibleFields' => ['user_id' => false]
            ]);
            if ($this->Articles->save($article)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('Your article has been updated.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to update your article.'));
        }
        $tags = $this->Articles->Tags->find('list');

        $this->set('article', $article);
        $this->set('tags', $tags);

    }
```

The query should be executed only once at this line:

```
 $article = $this->Articles
            ->findBySlug($slug)
            ->contain('Tags') // load associated Tags
            ->firstOrFail();
```

Correct?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, the debugkit is loaded two times. See in the bootstrap.php config file. If is there remove it because in 3.6 is loading in the Application.php